# How to parse data from two APIs

Tags: parsing, swiftui

I'm making an app where I need to parse data from two APIs ([first](https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets) and [second](https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches)). I figured out how to get data from the first API, but there was a problem with the second one. I work with the first API as follows.

For the first API, I use this model, then in the View I create the @State property and in the Body() I call the variables I need through dot syntax.

```
// MARK: - API
class InfoApi {
    func getRockets(completion: @escaping ([RocketInfo]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets") else {
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let rocketsInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode([RocketInfo].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(rocketsInfo)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}

// MARK: - ROCKET MODEL
struct RocketInfo: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let first_flight: String
    let cost_per_launch: Int
}

// MARK: - CONTENT VIEW
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rockets: [RocketInfo] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if rockets.isEmpty {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(rockets) { rocket in
                        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                            VStack {
                                //MARK: - HEADER IMAGE
                                Image("Image2")
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(height: 190, alignment: .center)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 32)
                                
                                //MARK: - INFO
                                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(rocket.name)
                                            .font(.title)
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("First flight")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(rocket.first_flight)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Country")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(rocket.country)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Cost per launch")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("$\(rocket.cost_per_launch / 1000000)M")
                                    }
                                } //: VSTACK
                                .padding(.horizontal, 32)
                                
                                //MARK: - LAUNCHES BUTTON
                                NavigationLink {
                                    LaunchDetailView()
                                } label: {
                                    Text("Launches".uppercased())
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 56, maxHeight: 56, alignment: .center)
                                        .background(
                                            Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill)
                                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous))
                                        )
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                                        .padding(32)
                                }
                            } //: VSTACK
                        } //: SCROLL
                    } //: LOOP
                } //: TAB
                .tabViewStyle(.page)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            }
        } //: NAVIGATION
        .onAppear {
            InfoApi().getRockets { rockets in
                self.rockets = rockets
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

The problem with the second API is that it contains a list of launches of all four rockets that are in the first API, and each of these launches has an individual ID that matches the ID of one of the four rockets from the first API.

**In short**, the **first API** contains a list of **4 rockets** and the parameters of each of them, and the **second API** contains a list of **all launches** of these rockets.
*Note*: I looked through the second API and found that one of the four rockets had no launches at all, and the other one had as many as 160. To be honest, I can't even just parse the entire list of launches from the second API, using the same model as for the first API, but changing the link to this API itself.

[image]

Each launch has an ID that matches the ID of one of the four rockets in the first API. In my application there are four tabs with information about each rocket and a button that leads to another View where information about all the launches of this rocket (name, date and whether the launch was successful) should be displayed.

1. I do not know how to update my model so that I can parse information from two APIs at once.
2. I also can't figure out how I can display information about all launches of a particular rocket on a separate View, having first checked that their IDs match to particular rocket ID from the first API.

Comment: well for the launch API, you need a `Launch` model appropriate for the json data you get from the server.
Just like you have with the `RocketInfo` for the rockets API. You call it just like `getRockets()` but with the launch url, eg `getLaunches(...)`.
Then you loop over the rockets and filter the launches for that rocket. The API may also allow you to retrieve only those launches for the given rocket id as a parameter.

Comment: Note: your `struct RocketInfo` should have`let id: String` **not**  `let id = UUID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT-1:

The best thing to do, is to restructure your code and use a
`ObservableObject class` to do all fetching, processing and publishing.

Here is some example code using an `ObservableObject` class.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var spacex = SpacexModel() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if spacex.loadingRockets || spacex.loadingLaunches {  // <-- here
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(spacex.rockets) { rocket in  // <-- here
                        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                            VStack {
                                //MARK: - HEADER IMAGE
                                Image(systemName: "globe") // <-- for testing
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 190, height: 190, alignment: .center)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 32)
                                
                                //MARK: - INFO
                                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(rocket.name).font(.title)
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("First flight")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(rocket.first_flight)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Country")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(rocket.country)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Cost per launch")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("$\(rocket.cost_per_launch / 1000000)M")
                                    }
                                } //: VSTACK
                                .padding(.horizontal, 32)
                                
                                //MARK: - LAUNCHES BUTTON
                                NavigationLink {
                                    LaunchDetailView(rocket: rocket)  // <-- here
                                } label: {
                                    Text("Launches".uppercased())
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 56, maxHeight: 56, alignment: .center)
                                        .background(
                                            Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill)
                                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous))
                                        )
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                                        .padding(32)
                                }
                            } //: VSTACK
                        } //: SCROLL
                    } //: LOOP
                } //: TAB
                .tabViewStyle(.page)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            }
        } //: NAVIGATION
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .environmentObject(spacex) // <-- here
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    }
}

struct LaunchDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var spacex: SpacexModel  // <-- here
    let rocket: RocketInfo    // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("launches for \(rocket.name)").foregroundColor(.blue)
            List {
                ForEach(spacex.launchesFor(rocket)) { launch in
                    VStack {
                        Text(launch.name).foregroundColor(.green)
                        Text("launch \(launch.details ?? "no details")")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class SpacexModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var rockets = [RocketInfo]()
    @Published var launches = [LaunchInfo]()
    
    @Published var loadingRockets = false
    @Published var loadingLaunches = false
    
    init() {
        getRockets()
        getLaunches()
    }
    
    func getRockets() {
        self.loadingRockets = true
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets") else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            // todo deal with errors
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    self.rockets = try JSONDecoder().decode([RocketInfo].self, from: data)
                    self.loadingRockets = false
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func getLaunches() {
        self.loadingLaunches = true
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches") else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            // todo deal with errors
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    self.launches = try JSONDecoder().decode([LaunchInfo].self, from: data)
                    self.loadingLaunches = false
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func launchesFor(_ rocket: RocketInfo) -> [LaunchInfo] {
        return launches.filter{ $0.rocket == rocket.id }
    }
    
}




struct RocketInfo: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String  // <-- here
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let first_flight: String
    let cost_per_launch: Int
    // ...
}

struct LaunchInfo: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let rocket: String  // <-- here
    let details: String?
    let crew, ships, capsules, payloads: [String]
    let name: String
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot.